# No message body writer

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I have a generated JAXB class (from an XSD).  I'm able to return as XML and JSON, but as soon as I add text/html to my Produces annotation, I get a:

```
"No message body writer for response class Employee"
```

Here's my API:

```
@GET
@Path("/employee/{employeeId}/getEmployeeById")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/html"})
public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathParam("employeeId") String employeeId);
```

Here's my client call (using CXF client):

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(basePath);
    client = client.path("employeeervice/employee/1/getEmployeeById").
    accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE).type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE);
```

The client response is 500.

Calling the same API passing in application/xml, it works fine.

```
Employee e = client.path("employeeservice/employee/1/getEmployeeById")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(Employee.class);
```

Is there something I need to do differently for text/html ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions listed in this SO answer [CXF: No message body writer found for class - automatically mapping non-simple resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312030/cxf-no-message-body-writer-found-for-class-automatically-mapping-non-simple-r)
I modified the annotations for text/html but it pretty much just worked. Also might want to ensure your POJO implements Serializable too.