# JSONProvider namespaceMap config in web.xml for Apache CXF

Tags: json, jax-rs, cxf

I need to pass a `namespaceMap` to the JSONProvider configuration via `web.xml` file in Apache CXF.

I do not use Spring on this application and do not do programmatic configuration of Providers like this question suggests: [CXF: No message body writer found for class - automatically mapping non-simple resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312030/)

Rather use configuration in the style of [this non-Spring example from the CXF code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/systests/jaxrs/src/test/resources/jaxrs_non_spring/WEB-INF/web.xml).

But, the example does not show how to provide a `namespaceMap` and I'm unsure of how to specify a map in that style of configuration.

I'm going ahead with some trial-and-error.

Anyone know of a reference guide for the syntax for the `JSONProvider` config via  `web.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a reference guide, but did manage to solve the configuration issue by some code spelunking and [this mailing list thread from the archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201109.mbox/%3C54D643671441BC4B9A4D90EABEB018160859C333A6%40DEWDFECCR03.wdf.sap.corp%3E).

For some reason, the suggestion from that mailing list thread didn't work (it was ignoring the custom JSONProvider from the `web.xml`).  I may have had other problems.

Ultimately, I moved away from the idea of `web.xml` configuration since it was already used to provide a `javax.ws.rs.Application` and (from looking @ CXF code), it appears that CXF ignore `init-param` elements from `web.xml` if it finds an Application.

Further, there doesn't seem be a way of expressing Map types in the `web.xml` config.  That's conjecture based on the thread and looking at the code, so I can't 100% confirm.

This is what my web.xml looks like (same before and after these changes):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>my.javax-ws-rs.Application</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

It was in the `my.javax-ws-rs.Application` class that I needed to make changes.

Simply added a new `JSONProvider` to the list of singletons in there:

```
@Override
public Set< Object> getSingletons() {
    final Set< Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

   // [SNIP -- existing singletons]
    singletons.add( new my.provider.MyJSONProvider() );

    return singletons;
}
```

The definition of `my.provider.MyJSONProvider` is where the rest of the magic happens (yes, it's the "programmatic" configuration that I said I didn't have, but ultimately had to resort to):

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) 
@Provider
public class MyJSONProvider<T> extends JSONProvider<T> {

  public AdministrationUtilisatuerJSONProvider() {

    {
        Map<String, String> newNamespaceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        XmlSchema resource1SchemaAnnotation = Resource1.class.getPackage().getAnnotation(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema.class);
        String resource1Namespace = resource1SchemaAnnotation.namespace();
        newNamespaceMap.put( resource1Namespace, "resource1JsonPrefix" );

        XmlSchema resource2SchemaAnnotation = Resource2.class.getPackage().getAnnotation(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema.class);
        String resource2Namespace = resource2SchemaAnnotation.namespace();
        newNamespaceMap.put( resource2Namespace, "resource2JsonPrefix" );

        setNamespaceMap(newNamespaceMap);
    }

    // Or set this to "true" to ignore all that namespace stuff
    // setIgnoreNamespaces(true);

    // Don't write namespace for default xsi-type elements.
    setWriteXsiType(false);

    // [SNIP] -- Other JSONProvider configuration.  
    //           Check source from CXF, but few comments in code.

  }
```

One final note about getting Jettison-based JSON working in CXF:  you also need the `cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers-X.Y.Z.jar` on your classpath.  This isn't documented in the CXF `WHICH_JARS` file, but is required.