# Error on deploying Object Storage in Bluemix using openstack4j

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack, object-storage

I am currently using openstack4j library to connect to Object Storage in Bluemix. When I try running the java code locally as a java application, the connection seems to work but when I deployed the same code as we Java web application in Bluemix, I get the following error below. The code that is failing happens when I try to execute the authenticate method:

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builderV3()
                 .endpoint(auth_url)
                 .credentials(username, password)
                 .scopeToProject(projectIdent, domainIdent)
                 .authenticate();

 Exception thrown by application class 'org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invoke:58'
org.openstack4j.api.exceptions.ConnectionException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.domain.v3.KeystoneAuth, ContentType: application/json
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invoke(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:58)
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:33)
at org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor.execute(HttpExecutor.java:51)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.authenticateV3(OSAuthenticator.java:156)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.invoke(OSAuthenticator.java:78)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:163)
at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:127)
at com.ibm.sample.ObjectStorageService.(ObjectStorageService.java:36)
at wasdev.sample.servlet.SimpleServlet.doGet(SimpleServlet.java:30)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.domain.v3.KeystoneAuth, ContentType: application/json
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doResponse(WebClient.java:1206)
at [internal classes]
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpCommand.execute(HttpCommand.java:79)
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invokeRequest(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:65)
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invoke(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:56)
... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.domain.v3.KeystoneAuth, ContentType: application/json
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$BodyWriter.doWriteBody(WebClient.java:1286)
... 16 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: No message body writer has been found for class org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.domain.v3.KeystoneAuth, ContentType: application/json
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.reportMessageHandlerProblem(AbstractClient.java:758)
... 16 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.domain.v3.KeystoneAuth["id"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:215)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
at org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.domain.v3.KeystoneAuth.getId(KeystoneAuth.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:285)
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is caused by a jar file conflict between the default set of jar files included in the WebSphere Liberty Profile and the jar files pulled in by the use of OpenStack4J.  Most likely, the culprit is jaxrs-2.0, which pulls Jersey dependencies.

The Bluemix docs for the Liberty profile lists jar files automatically included here:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

( Search for this text on that page: The entire default Liberty server.xml configuration file is as follows)

To solve the problem, deploy your app to Bluemix as normal..and it will fail per above.

Then issue cloud foundry commands (cf) to instruct WebSphere Liberty not to load its entire list of default jars.

Here is an example cf command that trims the default list of jars loaded by WebSphere Liberty down to only 2 jar files and gets rid of jaxrs:

```
cf set-env <your app name here> JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY "app_archive: {features: [jsp-2.3, websocket-1.1]}"
```

After issuing the above command, you have to "restage" your Liberty app for the changes to take effect:

```
cf restage <your app name here>
```

At this point, your openstack4j calls should work.  You will have to determine based on your code what this list should include:

```
{features: [jsp-2.3, websocket-1.1]}
```

There are other options to avoid classpath conflicts.  You can download the OpenStack4J source code, modify the pom files to shade the dependencies and use this custom version of openstack4j with Bluemix.

The WebSphere Liberty documentation suggests using "reverse class loading" but that does not sound like the best approach.

Comment: +1 Well this worked for me when i tried as separate web app (POC purpose), but when i did the same in my integrated environment. it did not work. resulting in same issue? any pointers ??

Comment: I solved this issue by reverse class loading... set the parent class loading last.

Comment: Yes, reverse class loading is another option.  Glad you got that to work ! Reverse class loading , in general, feels like a hack to me, so I elected not to do that for my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to a difference in the java environments from your development machine to Bluemix.  It is not specific to openstack or keystone.

I would suggest reviewing the following stack overflow issue -- it suggests a number of configuration changes:

[CXF: No message body writer found for class - automatically mapping non-simple resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312030/cxf-no-message-body-writer-found-for-class-automatically-mapping-non-simple-r)

If you don't have control over the providers, I'd open a Bluemix support ticket and ask which ones/versions are part of the environment.